# Throw Validation On Quote - Deal duration(Between Start date and Endate) can't be less than 1 year (or 12 months)

Tags: validation-rule, cpq

I want to throw Validation on Quote whenever user enters start date and end date, they should get an error if the deal duration is less than 1 year

E.g. :- Start Date is 14/9/2022 and End date is 13/9/2023 (No error)
but if Start Date is 14/9/2022and end date is any date less than 13/9/2023 we should throw error.

Also how we handle same validation for if in between deal duration, I have an extra day in February ( leap year)

My current validation

`EndDate__c - StartDate__c < 365` (Not handled for Leap year)

Can someone help?

Comment: Are you just asking for how to do the leap year or how to do the whole thing?

Comment: @fred I want help on the whole thing

Answer (score 1):

Using formulas to work with dates and times is usually fairly dubious and an exercise in frustration.

This particular situation shouldn't be *too* bad though. The `EndDate__c - StartDate__c` bit is fine, you just have to determine if the difference needs to be `>= 365` or `>= 366`.

After a little thought, I think you can detect if you need to account for a leap year if:

- The year of the Start Date, modulo 4, is 0 (i.e. the year is a multiple of 4) and the Start Date's month is < 3 (i.e. it starts before March 1 of a leap year)
- Or, the year of the End Date, modulo 4, is 0 and the End Date's month is > 2

That could return `365` instead of `366` when, for example, the Start Date was 2023-01-01 and the End Date was 2025-01-02, but at that point your day difference will be greater than 366 anyway (the maximum value that you need to adhere to), so it doesn't matter.

So the general form of the formula you're looking for here is (in psuedocode)

```
[Difference between end date and start date] 
<
/* The result of this IF() is a number, so we can use it in a comparison */
IF(
    OR(
        [that start date condition], 
        [that end date condition]
    ),
    366,
    365
)
```

Comment: This doesn't account for the "no leap years on each new century unless also divisible by 400", but I'll leave that as an exercise to the reader (and also, it'll be 76 years before that'll be an honest concern)